# How to attach a handlebar to your navigation-drawer

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, navigation-drawer

I want to use a chevron icon to open/close a Vuetify v-navigation-drawer. How can I stick this icon to the edge of the navigation-drawer (where 50% of the icon overlaps the drawer and vertically aligned)? When opening the drawer the icon is supposed to stay in postion and move with the drawer.

I tried to fix this with an empty mini-variant and a Floating Action Button attached to it but this doesn't meet the requirements (e.g. not able to position the correct background color, see image: https://grinjo.nl/clip.jpg).

```
    <v-navigation-drawer
      floating
      v-model="rightDrawer"
      right
      fixed
      permanent
      color="transparent"
      :mini-variant.sync="rightDrawer"
    >
        <v-btn
          fab
          absolute
          justify="center"
          left
          color="white"
          @click="rightDrawer = !rightDrawer"
          :style="{left: 0, top: '50%', transform:'translateY(-50%)'}"
        >
          <v-icon v-if="rightDrawer">mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>
          <v-icon v-else>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
```

Comment: Absolute uses a relative parent, you can not use absolute to a fixed parent. Wrap the nav with a relative container or better yet, use translateX(-half the button width) or margin-left: -half the button width. as long as the nav is not set to overflow hidden.

Comment: @MichaelMano, good insights! If you can add your comment as an answer with the code placed in the correct space that would be helpful.

Comment: @MichaelMano, [seriously](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/oanjk5u7/)? `position: absolute` uses the closest positioned parent as reference. And by positioned we mean any element with a `position` value other than `static`. Which includes `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed` and `sticky`. Please read [the standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#absolute-position).

Comment: @Arthur, while you can look at the example I used to disprove Michael's false statement for how you can place an item relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if you need a specific example for your case, please set up a *runnable* [mcve], adding all relevant applied style rules. If you need a multi-file node-like online editor, use codesandbox.io or similar.

Comment: @tao, I build a simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/grinjo/jw3sh9n8/75/ Problem I'm facing: the overflow hidden for the navigation-drawer when I choose this solution with the mini-variant.

Comment: There we go! https://jsfiddle.net/grinjo/jw3sh9n8/81/ But still hoping for a better solution perhaps... This one is a little bit hacky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigation drawer with handlebar: https://jsfiddle.net/grinjo/jw3sh9n8/81

This did the magic:

Vue:

```
<v-btn
    absolute
    right
    fab
    @click="drawer = !drawer"
    :style="{top: '50%', transform:'translate(75%, -50%)'}"
>
```

CSS:

```
.v-navigation-drawer--mini-variant, .v-navigation-drawer {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Worked for me! Glad I found your answer.  I have been fiddling too much with this already.